# <ListView> of images - How open URL via TapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can we open a URL (via TapGestureRecognizer) that is bound to a  of images?

My ListView's ItemsSource is _partners (type of List).

The Partner class has two properties - WebUrl and ImageUrl.

```
<ListView x:Name="partnersListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" Text="{Binding WebUrl}" />-->
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Image_TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The list is showing images only, and I would like the app to navigate to a web site when the user taps the image. However, the following code - unsurprisingly - doesn't work.

```
private void Image_TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var tappedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;

        var partner = tappedMenuItem.CommandParameter as Partner;

        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(partner.WebUrl));
    }
```

Any suggestions, please?


Please note:

I want to keep the TapGestureRecognizer in XAML - not in the code-behind.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason for keeping this on the UI page? Can't you just bind the Item Selected property of the list view to a prop on your ViewModel and react to that to trigger the OpenURI?

Comment: I don't have a ViewModel page - everything on every page is set up through code-behind. I'm a beginner, so these are my first steps, so go easy on me :)

Comment: Ok but there is no difference... you can bind SelectedItem to a property on your View code behind too. Same way you used binding for the Image Source.

Comment: @Depechie could you please elaborate, show me the exact code and make it into an answer so I can accept it? Pretty please?

Comment: Try to create UriBuilder, May be uri format wrong here is code-var uri = new UriBuilder(CategoryObject.Website).Uri;
      Device.OpenUri(uri);

Comment: Good call from Pratius, my remark was about the fact that maybe the complete method is not working ( as in you are not even reaching the _Tapped method ). So maybe tell us first in detail what is not working :) If needed I'll draft up an example.

Comment: @Depechie the method is working and the code IS reaching the method. The problem is I don't know how to get the sender and extract the Partner model from it so I can reach the WebUrl property on the Partner class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The list is showing images only, and I would like the app to navigate to a web site when the user taps the image. However, the following code - unsurprisingly - doesn't work.

`CommandParameter` is just for `Command`, you can't get it from a tap event handler. To accomplish your requirement, you can either use [`TappedCallback`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.TappedCallback/) together with [`TappedCallbackParameter`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.TappedCallbackParameter/) or use [`Command`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.Command/) together with [`CommandParameter`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameter/):

**Method 1(`TapppedCallback` and `TappedCallbackParameter`):**

1. Modify your `Partner` class to hold an `Action<View,object>`:

   ```
   public class Partner
   {
       public Partner(string weburl, string imageurl)
       {
           this.WebUrl = weburl;
           this.ImageUrl = imageurl;
       }

       public Partner(string weburl, string imageurl, Action<View, object> callback) : this(weburl, imageurl)
       {
           this.CallBack = callback;
       }

       public Action<View, object> CallBack { get; set; }

       public string WebUrl { get; set; }
       public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

   }
   ```
2. In your code-behind, define a `TappedCallback` function like below and initialize the items source with the this function:

   ```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
       public MainPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           List<Partner> list = new List<Partner>
           {
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",TappedCallback),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",TappedCallback),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",TappedCallback),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",TappedCallback),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",TappedCallback),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",TappedCallback)
           };
           partnersListView.ItemsSource = list;

       }

       private void TappedCallback(View sender,object param)
       {
           var Partner = param as Partner;

           Device.OpenUri(new Uri(Partner.WebUrl));
       }

   }
   ```
3. Use `TappedCallback` in Xaml:

   ```
   <ListView x:Name="partnersListView">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <!--<ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" Text="{Binding WebUrl}" />-->
               <ViewCell>
                   <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">
                       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                           <TapGestureRecognizer   TappedCallback="{Binding CallBack}" TappedCallbackParameter="{Binding .}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1"  />
                       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                   </Image>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   ```

**Method 2(`Command` and `CommandParameter`):**

1. Define an `ICommand` in your Partner class and constructor to accept `ICommand`:

   ```
   public class Partner
   {
       public Partner(string weburl, string imageurl)
       {
           this.WebUrl = weburl;
           this.ImageUrl = imageurl;
       }


       public Partner(string weburl, string imageurl, ICommand command) : this(weburl, imageurl)
       {
           this.TapCommand = command;
       }

       public string WebUrl { get; set; }
       public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

       public ICommand TapCommand { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create a `MyCommand` class to implement the `ICommand` interface :

   ```
   public class MyCommand : ICommand
   {
       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
       {
           return true;
       }

       public void Execute(object parameter)
       {
           var Partner = parameter as Partner;

           Device.OpenUri(new Uri(Partner.WebUrl));
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your code-behind initialize your items source with a new `MyCommand` object:

   ```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
       public MainPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           List<Partner> list = new List<Partner>
           {
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",new MyCommand()),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",new MyCommand()),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",new MyCommand()),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",new MyCommand()),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",new MyCommand()),
               new Partner("http://www.url.com","timg.jpg",new MyCommand())
           };
           partnersListView.ItemsSource = list;
       }

   }
   ```
4. Use `Command` in `Xaml`:

   ```
   <ListView x:Name="partnersListView">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <!--<ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" Text="{Binding WebUrl}" />-->
               <ViewCell>
                   <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">
                       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                           <TapGestureRecognizer   Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1"  />
                       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                   </Image>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to tackle this problem, is to bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView` to a property on your page.

So in your View

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPartner}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And in the Code Behind

```
public Partner SelectedPartner
{
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
            Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri(value.WebUrl));
    }
}
```